# Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics.Vectors" in Xamarin Forms 5 project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building a new Xamarin Forms 5 app using VS 2022 17.1.1. Everything in the project appears to be up-to-date.

I've been working on this project for a while and never had this issue. All of a sudden it just appeared today. The last action I took was to install the `Plugin.InAppBilling` package, thought the package in question is not used by the `Plugin.InAppBilling` package.

The error is as follows:

[image]

All I can see is that the shared project is using `System.Numerics.Vectors` version `4.5.0`  and it seems to be dependency of `Xamarin.Essentials` which is version `1.7.1` in my project.

However, the version number of `System.Numerics.Vectors` seems to be `2.0.5.0` in the Android and iOS projects.

I found the `GitHub` issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/904) but I'm not seeing any clear resolution to this issue. Even though it appears to be a warning, in my case, I can no longer run the app because I keep getting deployment error to the Android Emulator or actual device. It simply refuses to deploy my app to the device/emulator. So, it's really NOT a warning in my case. It's a show-stopper. I'm a bit surprised about how lightly the Xamarin Essentials folks seem to have taken this issue on GitHub.

Has anyone actually resolved this issue? If so, what's the solution?

BTW, in my case both the `Android` and the `iOS` projects are throwing this error/warning and both use `System.Numberics.Vectors` version `2.0.5.0` even though the shared project has version `4.5.0` installed as a dependency undre Xamarin Esssentials.

I'd appreciate some pointers on how to make this issue disappear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing the reference to System.Numerics.Vectors in my Xamarin IOS project file.  Another package referenced it already so I still have it.

Answer (score -1):

At first, you can try to update the `Xamarin.Essentials` package in the Android and IOS project with the nuget package manager to the version 1.7.1.

And then, if the error is still here, you can right click the reference and remove the reference of the `System.Numberics.Vectors` `2.0.5.0` both in your Android and IOS project. Then download the `System.Numberics.Vectors` `4.5.0` in the nuget package manager both too.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work. The `Xamarin.Essentials` was already 1.7.1 on all three projects. I did remove `System.Numerics.Vectors` manually from Android and iOS projects and added the NuGet package which was version 4.5.0 but still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is but something else must've been causing the problem. I restored code from my repo to undo the most recent changes I made to the code and started adding things step by step. Everything is working now and the shared project still has version 4.5 for `System.Numerics.Vectors` while Android and iOS projects still have version `2.0.5.0`. Clearly, this version difference is not the cause of the problem though I don't know what caused it.

Comment: So the conflict is disappear now? It's strange.

Comment: Exactly! I'm trying to figure out what I did that may have caused it. The only thing I can think of so far is that I packaged the project in order to submit it to Google Play.

Comment: You can try to create a new project and add the reference of the package `Plugin.InAppBilling` and then build it to check the conflict will appear or not.